# Powershell date Comparison not working in if statement

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to compare dates using the powershell `Get-Date` commandlet.  An example of how I am using the `Get-Date` command is as follows.

```
$Date1 = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" -Day 31 -Hour 07 -Minute 30 -Month 12 -Second 00 -Year 2021
```

If `$Date1` above was compared to the following `$Date2` below using a simple

```
if ($Date1 -lt $Date2)
{
    Write-Host Date1 is before Date2
}
```

then `Write-Host` would be excuted. This is expected behaviour.

```
$Date2 = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" -Day 31 -Hour 08 -Minute 30 -Month 12 -Second 00 -Year 2021
```

If `$Date2` was  changed to the following:

```
$Date2 = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" -Day 01 -Hour 08 -Minute 30 -Month 1 -Second 00 -Year 2022
```

The if statement would not excute `Write-Host` even though the `$Date2` variable is still after `$Date1`.

Answer (score 2):

when you use `Get-Date` with `-Format` powershell compares the first item in the format(in your case 'dd'). powershell comapres the date in the order in which you have mentioned the `-format`. for example if both the dates are equal then it will check months and so on. there is two solutions either you remove the format and use for example

```
$Date1=get-date 2021-31-02 
$date2=get-date 2022-01-01
if ($Date1 -lt $Date2){
    Write-Host "Date1 is before Date2" 
}
else{
    Write-Host "Date1 is after Date2"
}
```

or you can reverse the `-format` which is best suited for your use.

```
$Date1 = Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" -Day 31 -Hour 07 -Minute 30 -Month 1 -Second 00 -Year 2021
$Date2 = Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" -Day 01 -Hour 08 -Minute 30 -Month 1 -Second 00 -Year 2022 
 if ($Date1 -lt $Date2){
        Write-Host "Date1 is before Date2" 
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Date1 is after Date2"
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, really helped me understand why my comparison wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the dates, remove `Format` from your `Get-Date`. When you use `Format` you get string instead of `DateTime` object:

```bsh
PS> $Date1 = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" -Day 31 -Hour 07 -Minute 30 -Month 12 -Second 00 -Year 2021
PS> $Date1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

When you remove `Format` you receive `DateTime` and you can compare directly:

```bsh
PS> $Date1 = Get-Date -Day 31 -Hour 07 -Minute 30 -Month 12 -Second 00 -Year 2021
PS> $Date1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType

PS> $Date2 = Get-Date -Day 31 -Hour 08 -Minute 30 -Month 12 -Second 00 -Year 2021
PS> $Date3 = Get-Date -Day 01 -Hour 08 -Minute 30 -Month 1 -Second 00 -Year 2022
PS> $date1 -lt $date2
True
PS> $date1 -lt $date3
True
```

Comment: Your option does not work in an IF statement though... unless you bracket it properly: (if ((get-date) -lt "$Date1"){something you want to do if $True}

Comment: @PatrickBurwell you're right, proper use of brackets is very important. The example you pasted doesn't run for me unless you remove the first opening bracket before the `if` keyword. But anyway, that's a broader topic, not in the scope of this answer.
If anyone wants to read more about it, see [about Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-7.2)